# Passing mock boto3 client in init.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, moto

I am trying to figure out how to pass a mock boto3 client to init.py with pytest, but am having some trouble. When I pass my fixture into the function I'm trying to test, the function called in init.py still tries to use a real instance of the boto client when get_secret is called instead of the one I'm mocking.  Wondering what I am doing wrong here?

As an example:

**init.py**

```py
from helpers.token_helper import get_token
from my_jobs.jobs import job_1, job_2

params = {'token': get_token()}
job_1()
job_2(params)
```

**token_helper.py**

```py
import os
from aws_helper import get_secret

def get_token():
    token = os.getenv("MY_TOKEN")
    if not token:
        try:
            token = get_secret("my-secret/my-token")
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"could not get token")
    return token
```

**aws_helper.py**

```py
import boto3

def get_secret(secret_name):
    client = boto3.client("secretsmanager", region_name="us-east-1")
    try:
        response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
        return response["SecretString"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

**jobs.py**

```py
def job_1():
    return 'yay'

def job_2(params):
    print(params)
    return 'boo'
```

**test_jobs.py**

```py
import pytest
import boto3
import moto
from my_jobs.jobs import job_1

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def mock_boto3_client():
    with moto.mock_secretsmanager():
        client = boto3.client("secretsmanager", region_name="us-east-1")
        secret_name = "my-test-secret"
        secret_value = "my-test-secret-value"
        client.create_secret(Name=secret_name, SecretString=secret_value)
        yield client

def test_job_1(mock_boto3_client):
    response = job_1()
    assert response == 'yay'
```

Comment: `get_token()` in init.py is called/executed before the mock starts, so that will always go to AWS

Comment: Also: Moto is a bit finicky with import order, so that may also be an issue. The docs explain it quite well (and have a workaround): http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/getting_started.html#what-about-those-pesky-imports